# Is there any performance boost in caching an array lookup within a loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, loops

Is there any performance boost in caching an array read within a loop, versus performing an array lookup with each loop iteration?

```
for (var i = 0; i < HEADER_DATA_KEYS.length; i++) {
    var headerKey = HEADER_DATA_KEYS[i];
    var msgVal = message[headerKey];
    doStuff(msgVal);
}
```

Versus:

```
for (var i = 0; i < HEADER_DATA_KEYS.length; i++) {
    var msgVal = message[HEADER_DATA_KEYS[i]];
    doStuff(msgVal);
}
```

Edit: yes, sorry wrong use of memoization. Thank you!

Comment: Try http://jsperf.com And yep both samples looks the same.

Comment: I do not see any memoization? Both examples are equivalent... there's one less variable declaration/assignation in the second one but in terms of performance it shouldn't change much.

Comment: In this situation, I wouldn't even call this memoization. You're just assigning the array value to a local variable, and there's really no difference between the two here as far as the JavaScript compiler is concerned.

Comment: The first one will be slower, but the difference will be only a few milliseconds at most.

Comment: @Sparky Huuuuuuge assertions. Both the "will" and the meaningless time difference you pulled out of thin air.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It's usually a bad habit to speak without facts, but in this case I think it was an honest assumption.

Comment: And what about `for (var i = 0; i < HEADER_DATA_KEYS.length; i++) {
    doStuff(message[HEADER_DATA_KEYS[i]]);
}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some confusion of terminology.

*Memoization* is something that you do to functions to make subsequent *re*computations cheaper. It's a classic example of a time/space trade off: The memo (usually a dictionary) takes up more space, but executes in minimal time.

Now, mathematically speaking, a JavaScript "array" *is* a function from **N** (non-negative integers) to **Object** (or whatever is stored in the array). But, with respect to time, arrays are already the cheapest functions to execute. Moreoever, they're also usually the most expensive in terms of space.

So, in other words: An array is already the "most memoized" possible function.

Answer (score 0):

Memoization is when you store the result of a complex computation to avoid recomputing it the next time you need it.

`var headerKey = HEADER_DATA_KEYS[i];` has nothing to do with memorization, you are simply assigning a value to a variable.

I haven't ran a performance test case, but I feel confident enough to say that the performance overhead of assigning a value to a variable is so minimal that it shouldn't even be considered in normal circumstances.

EDIT:

http://jsperf.com/var-assignation-cost

```
IE 11:

With assignation: 276,478,194 op/sec
Without: 327,503,873 op/sec
```

Comment: wow, IE doesn't seem like optimizing out the obviously unused variable. this is depressing. I get only a 0.28% difference (1,065,615,176 OPS vs. 1,072,567,957) in Chrome.